# Test failing when executed in a different order

Tags: testing, raku

When I execute this program:

```
use Test;
use NativeCall;

constant LIB  = ('gsl', v23);

sub gsl_sf_airy_Ai(num64 $x, uint32 $mode --> num64) is native(LIB) is export { * }
sub Ai(Numeric $x, UInt $mode --> Num) is export { gsl_sf_airy_Ai($x.Num, $mode) }

ok Ai(0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 1';
ok gsl_sf_airy_Ai(0e0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 2';
```

the tests work fine, even if I swap the two "ok" tests this way:

```
ok gsl_sf_airy_Ai(0e0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 2';
ok Ai(0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 1';
```

If I move the declarations to a module:

```
unit module mymodule;
use NativeCall;

constant LIB  = ('gsl', v23);

sub gsl_sf_airy_Ai(num64 $x, uint32 $mode --> num64) is native(LIB) is export { * }
sub Ai(Numeric $x, UInt $mode --> Num) is export { gsl_sf_airy_Ai($x.Num, $mode) }
```

and write a test program:

```
use Test;
use lib '.';
use mymodule;

ok Ai(0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 1';
ok gsl_sf_airy_Ai(0e0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 2';
```

again the two tests are executed without errors, but if I swap the last two lines:

```
ok gsl_sf_airy_Ai(0e0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 2';
ok Ai(0, 0) == 0.3550280538878172, 'Ai 1';
```

I get this error:
`Type check failed for return value; expected Num but got Whatever (*)` and I don't understand why.
I even suspected a possible memory corruption, so I executed the test program using valgrind, but apparently there's nothing wrong in that department.
Any hint?

Comment: Which version of Rakudo are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that information: 2019.07.1

Comment: Can you please point to some place to download the native library?

Comment: @jjmerelo it's the GNU Scientific Library, the libgsl23 Debian package. I'm in the process of writing an interface to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please re-test on the recently released rakudo 2019.11. There's a high chance that I already fixed this when I refactored the NativeCall setup code.